# iTerm2 doesn't work well with vim fold

Tags: vim, iterm2

I'm using iTerm2 on Macbook now. But there is a problem when I edit a cpp file in vim and scrolling down. here is an image showing that. You can see the status bar is scrolled too, with text. 
How to deal with it?[image]

Comment: Can you echo $TERM ? Your $TERM type could be messed up causing vim to send the wrong characters. Also check the $TERM setting in iterm2.

Comment: I second that comment^ check $TERM, Check `iTerm / Preferences / Profiles / (YourProfile) / Terminal / Report Terminal Type`

Comment: I have checked $TERM, it's xterm-256color.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug of iTerm2 on version 2.1.4. Just now I have tried version 2.2.9 which is the latest test version with supporting os x El Capitan. And it works!